# How to figure out in which phase a maven plugin is executed?

Tags: maven

Assume a plugin author has failed to mention the default phase of a maven plugin in its documetnation and I want to figure it out.

Running `mvn -X verify` give output in the form of

```
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
```

which tells me that maven can print the same string five times to `stdout` followed by a listing in the form of

```
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.6:check (checkstyle)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: [...]
```

for every plugin followed by "Dependency collection stats" followed by debug output of plugins.

Do I have to assume - regarding the fact that even in 10000 lines of debug output with maximal verbosity (afaik) the work `phase` does not occur and search engines only reveal 1000s of duplicate explanations what a phase is in the maven lifecycle - that this is a secret to be kept.

I'm using maven 3.3.1 on Ubuntu 15.04 with Linux 4.0.1.

Comment: Are you talking about a particular plugin?

Comment: Take the `maven-formatter-plugin` (see http://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/0.4/index.html for details) as an example, but I'd like to keep the question generic.

Comment: well if the generated documentation is avaailable the default phase can be  under goals -> choose goal, then under attributes: "Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: process-sources."

Comment: Hm..Taking a look on the site http://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/0.4/format-mojo.html shows the information you are asking for?

Answer (score 4):

Good question :-)

I believe that the plugin author probablby just forgot the documentation? So the information on the goals and phases in the plugin information (hopefully).

For the maven-compiler-plugin, if you download the jar and extract it there is a plugin.xml in `maven-compiler-plugin-3.3\META-INF\maven\plugin.xml`

That plugin contains that mojo's (goals) and the phase they are configured for:

```
  <mojos>
    <mojo>
      <goal>compile</goal>
      <description>Compiles application sources</description>
      <requiresDependencyResolution>compile</requiresDependencyResolution>
      <requiresDirectInvocation>false</requiresDirectInvocation>
      <requiresProject>true</requiresProject>
      <requiresReports>false</requiresReports>
      <aggregator>false</aggregator>
      <requiresOnline>false</requiresOnline>
      <inheritedByDefault>true</inheritedByDefault>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <implementation>org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo</implementation>
      <language>java</language>
```

Here the compile goal runs in `<phase>` compile. I would hope the plugin your curious about contains this as well.

Comment: No the documentation is not forgotten. You might have not found it.

Comment: I used the compiler plugin just as an example - as the question does not refer to a concrete one.

Answer (score 3):

The default phase for a goal to be bound at is documented on the [appropriate plugin page.](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html)

For example the above doc shows for the goal `compile` the following:

```
Requires a Maven project to be executed.
Requires dependency resolution of artifacts in scope: compile.
The goal is thread-safe and supports parallel builds.
Since version: 2.0.
Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: compile.
```

This means (last line) by default the maven-compile-plugin is bound to the life cycle phase: `compile` if not overwritten. Furthermore the [reference documentation](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.1/maven-core/default-bindings.html) shows which plugins are bound to which phase.

Apart from the above if a plugin author has decided not to bind a plugin to a default life cycle it will not being part of the documentation. If a plugin author decided to bind a plugin to a life cycle phase this is automatically documented [cause it's generated from source code.](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/trunk/maven-compiler-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/CompilerMojo.java?revision=1517906&view=markup)

The code looks like this:

```java
@org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo( 
  name = "compile", 
  defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE, 
  threadSafe = true,
  requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE )
public class CompilerMojo
  extends AbstractCompilerMojo
  {
```

And from the above code the documentation will generated.

Comment: Considering your own answer and your comment on @wemu 's answer people might get the impression that documentation is generated automatically. This might be true if source code is considered documentation (which makes life hard for anybody but the creator of the source code) and the source code is actually accessible. As probably all maven artifacts need to be shipped with a plugin.xml (as described by @wemu) I feel this is a more reliable source of documentation.
Nonetheless, your answer delivers some additional interesting information, thx.